# Why is .NET ignoring my CORS policy for POST requests? "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check"

Tags: .net, cors

I have CORS configured to allow anything:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new DefaultForwardedHeaders());
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true));
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
```

GET requests work, but I get a CORS error when POSTing:

```
Access to fetch at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

In debugging I see that isOriginAllowed is never even called. Why is .net ignoring my CORS policy?

Comment: Whatever you do, never do this: `.AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true)`. Wildly insecure.

Comment: I know I'm just testing right now.